# What's the difference between coded width and width in FFprobe

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Pretty much the title, what's the difference between coded width (or coded height) and width (or height) in FFprobe, why are they sometimes different and which is the right one?

```
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1088
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some encoders require frame dimensions to be multiples of a certain number e.g. x264 and 16. So the encoder will pad the frame to a suitable number, if needed, and store the cropping values for the decoder. The coded size is the size before cropping.